# PostgreSQL - Consultar dados de um intervalo e trazer um limite de linhas mas espaçados

Tags: postgresql, query, otimização, select-limit

Bom dia Pessoal, tudo bem?

Estou com um problema de performance em um sistema e preciso resolver customizando uma SQL.

Imaginemos o seguinte cenário:
- Uma tabela com milhões de registros, cada registro tem um ID (PK) e um TIMESTAMP.

- Atualmente, consulto os dados pelo intervalo do TIMESTAMP, por exemplo, registros da ultima semana.
- Consideramos que nesse período de uma semana tenha 1.000.000 (um milhão) registros. Atualmente resgato esses valores para criar um gráfico.

Convenhamos que isso é custoso e um tanto estúpido visto que de um registro para o outro há mínima alteração de valores e preciso montar um gráfico de linha onde o valor de X é o TIMESTAMP.

DÚVIDA: Tem como determinar ao banco para me consultar esse intervalo mas me trazer até 1.000 registros apenas? Mas esses registros teriam que vir espaçados para poderem compreender todo o período, seria um tipo de amostragem. Tentar processar isso na programação do sistema é enviável.

Desde já deixo o meu obrigado para que puder me ajudar,
Gustavo Ferreira.

Comment: Tentou colocar um *LIMIT 0,1000* por exemplo?

Comment: Não. Eu não quero os primeiros 1000 registros, eu quero 1000 distribuídos entre o 1.000.000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar [Window Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/tutorial-window.html) para pegar por exemplo uma linha a cada 100 linhas ou pode usar algum tipo de agregação no banco, como por exemplo, transformar a `TIMESTAMP` em uma data e agrupar os valores por dia ou por hora usando uma agregação de média (`AVG`)

Comment: Gostei, vou pesquisar a respeito das duas formas.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

SELECT TO_CHAR(t.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:00:00') AS data, AVG(t.h24::NUMERIC) AS valor FROM telemetria t WHERE t.date >= (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '168 HOUR') GROUP BY data ORDER BY data DESC

Nesse caso estou buscando dados de 7 dias atrás. Os dados estão agrupados por data e hora pois há muitos registros com a mesma hora.

Quando preciso de um período mairo que 7 dias eu agrupo por dia, tendo a média diária do valor que preciso.

Obrigado pela contribuição Renato.